# Scraping Python advice needed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, screen-scraping, web-scraping, web-crawler

I need to get product ID from a commerce website. The product ID is the number series at the end of the URLs.

For example: `http://example.com/sp/123170/` has product ID `123170`.

Some requirements:

- Code must be written by Python
- Because the number of product is large, I want the software to be able to restart after it stops due to some reasons.
- Can run one time everyday.
- the new product is updated/added everyday so the software need to be able to deal with that. 
  if possible, I would love to work with Google app engine

Please recommend me some ideas and open source code for this job. I found **scrapy.org** and **Beautifulsoup**. Please also give me advice about them, which one is better for this purpose?

Comment: @Andbdrew well he is asking for recommendation, not code. So I think its a genuine question.

Comment: @SushantGupta fair enough, though scrapy and BeautifulSoup do different things, and they can be used together. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/faq.html#how-does-scrapy-compare-to-beautifulsoup-or-lxml

Comment: Hope this post might be useful to somebody regarding this. http://samranga.blogspot.com/2015/08/web-scraping-beginner-python.html It uses beautiful soup python library for web scraping with python. A detailed tutorial for a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For periodic scheduling you can look for [cron jobs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) in app engine.

Also, Scrapy is nice framework of web scraping. Other alternative you can go with is using beautiful soup and [requests API](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/) (supports authentication and multithreaded downloads).

But I would suggest BEFORE you scrap, see whether that commerce website has provided with some API.

Comment: Thanks. The website does not provide any API. Scrapy vs beautiful soup, which one is better?

Comment: <Personal preference, no rational reason:> I prefer using requests and beautiful soup. For db solution I like MongoDB since its schemaless and good for storing unstructured data. I have never used Scrapy in my apps.

Answer (score 1):

lxml.html is currently the best html parser for python. Parse your document into lxml, and use xpath to locate the data you need.

http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#parsing-html

Comment: Lxml has some problems if html isn't well-formed, plus it will take you more time to do it. Plus it's a C library, because of this it will be blazing fast, but you'll have problems in compiling on Windows

Comment: Beautifulsoup 4 use lxml now, so if lxml fail, it'll fail too.

Comment: thanks for all of your advices. I am quite new to web scraping. I dont know how to get product ID of all pages. Should I use a loop to go to each product page, check if the page exists. If page exits, then get product ID? But there are millions of product pages, it is impossible to use my method. Any recommendation ? Thank a lot.

Comment: @John: crawling millions of pages without permission is bad manners and borders on illegal. You'll want to contact the site in question and work out an acceptable way for you to get the data. They will either provide an API (maybe based on RSS) or a dump of the data. It may cost you money.

Comment: @John: If you try to do this on your own, and loop over all their pages, they will notice and permanently block your IP. I would.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a crawler and a way to persist data between each crawling session.

For the crawler, I recommend `scrapy`. It's really much better than rolling your own for most purposes. If you use `scrapy`, you don't need BeautifulSoup because Scrapy uses `lxml`, which in my opinion is currently the best Html parser

To persist data between session, you can store crawled data in a database, I prefer using [`sqlalchemy`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for this purpose, but this might not work for App Engine. `sqlalchemy` support a lot of database engines, among which sqlite3 is the easiest to setup.